# What does "skimming the cream off the milk" mean?

Tags: expressions

Some context:

The physicists Prandtl and von Kármán had a competition to solve an open problem in the field. Prandtl shared his unpublished data, as well as his "lieutenant" physicist, Frank Wattendorf, with von Kármán so that they would be on equal footing. Von Kármán ended up solving the problem first:

> Von Kármán was soon ready to deliver a decisive blow in his competition with Prandtl, who admitted defeat by saying that von Kármán had once again exercised "his well-known talent for skimming the cream off the milk."

I'm not sure what the expression "skimming the cream off the milk" means in this context.

Comment: Have you researched what "cream" is, and how it is separated from "raw" milk?

Comment: Ahh, I think I get it now: Prandtl is implying that von Kármán was only able to solve the problem because of the foundations established by Prandtl.

Comment: I think reasonable research here would be to give a dictionary definition of 'cream off'. This still leaves two possible interpretations (does it mean that von Kármán identified and used the important data, or that he received the kudos?) The 'often in an unfair way' note in at least one dictionary might be taken to imply some discontent in the acknowledgement that von Kármán had won the duel.

Comment: From my reading of the text, I think both interpretations hold.

Comment: 'Hold', certainly – hence the ambiguity. As to which one (or two)  was/were intended, that's POB.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I parse it as a prepositional phrase. You skim the cream. How? Off the milk. You skim the cream off the milk. Or if it is phrasal, you skim off the cream. How? From the milk. You skim off the cream from the milk.

Comment: @Mitch OP's question is solely about meaning. And this is obviously a metaphorical usage. I'm baffled as to why you are introducing syntax; this doesn't inform the answer.

Comment: @Mitch: Perhaps as a non-native Anglophone, Prandtl wasn't *entirely* familiar with the phrasal verb [**to cream off** (the best bits, usually undeservedly)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22he+creamed+off%22), so he felt more comfortable "spelling it out" (something native speakers wouldn't normally do except facetiously, for that idiomatic metaphoric association).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, FF: I introduced the syntax notions because you metioned 'cream off' as though it is a constituent. To me, it is not a constituent in that sentence: 'the cream' is a noun there, not a verb. So syntax informs semantics. And, FF, I've never heard of 'to cream off' as a verb. Maybe it's a BrE thing?

Comment: @Mitch [Farlex-WordNet {Princeton}](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/cream+off) include it as a M-W verb. Though it's _very_ common in the UK.

Comment: @Tazik_S Whatever controversy about the parsing, the meaning is that raw unhomogenized milk will separate with the cream rising to the top, and the cream is the tastiest part. The metaphor for winning by skimming the best part off the top should be clear.

Comment: One meaning of skim is "to move lightly and rapidly over the surface of". It is from 1650s, from the motion involved in skimming liquid. So rather than turning over every "rock" until a solution was found, Von Kármán skimmed over the rocks until he identified those promising enough (i.e. the cream) to yield a quick solution.